# Spring AMQP Connections

Tags: spring, amqp, spring-amqp

I, I have a Spring AMQP project with CachingConnectionFactory. I need to get some properties from the AMQP Connection, for example: State, Connected at, channels, and some runtime metrics. Is there any metrics support for the CachingConnectionFactory (like: https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2016/11/30/metrics-support-in-rabbitmq-java-client-4-0/).

I can use a ConnectionListener for some data, but i prefer get it at runtime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Spring AMQP 1.7.0 (released last week) supports the 4.0 client.

You can configure the underlying RabbitMQ `ConnectionFactory` and inject it into the `CachingConnectionFactory` [documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#connection-factory).

The connection factory can be created directly or using the Spring `RabbitConnectionFactoryBean`, which now supports setting the metrics collector.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it with version 1.7.0.RELEASE but I have this error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/rabbitmq/client/Connection; when I declare a queue:   Queue q = myAmqpAdmin().declareQueue();

Comment: That seems to indicate you have an old version of amqp-client on the classpath; not 4.0.x. The `String` parameter was added to the `newConnection` method fairly recently (3.6?). If you use maven or gradle you should get 4.0.1 transitively.

Comment: Thank you again! I had forgotten to update the version of amqp-client. One last question, what do you think is the best way to get the status of an AMQP connection?

Comment: "best" is subjective :) - it depends on what you mean. Since the caching connection factory uses one connection by default, you can call `createConnection()` and call `isOpen()`; or you can call `getCacheProperties()` to get info about connection(s) and channels. Or you can use the [com.rabbitmq:http-client](https://github.com/rabbitmq/hop) to get everything you would ever want to know about a connection over REST  `Client.getConnections()` or `Client.getConnection(String name)`. The current release is 1.1.0.RELEASE.

Comment: You're right. The question should have been: what would you use ...? I can not use REST, so I'll try the other two options. Thank you!